# How to fix UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u202f' in Python

Tags: python

My goal is to convert all html codes embedded in my csv file and convert those to pdf form. But i am having some issue on other html codes and it cannot proceed with conversion to pdf. Here's the current code:

```
import csv
import os
import pdfkitc  #imported pdfkit for html to pdf conversion

# path to the raw CSV file
csv_file_path = r"C:\Users\jdayao\Desktop\html_to_pdf\emails_body_202303211635.csv"    

# stored directory here the PDF files will be dumped
pdf_dir_path = r"C:\Users\jdayao\Desktop\sample_html"    

# to ensure the PDF directory exists
os.makedirs(pdf_dir_path, exist_ok=True)

options = { 'page-height': '1500.00', 'page-width': '210.00', 'encoding': 'utf8'}  

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = r"C:\Program 
Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")   

with open(csv_file_path, newline='', encoding = "utf8") as csv_file:   
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(reader)  # Skip the header row
    for row in reader:
        html_code = row[2]

        # this will generate a unique filename for the HTML and PDF files
        filename_base = f'{header[2]}_{row[0]}'
        html_file_path = f'{pdf_dir_path}\{filename_base}.html'
        pdf_file_path = f'{pdf_dir_path}\{filename_base}.pdf'

        # Write the HTML code to the HTML file
        with open(html_file_path, 'w') as html_file:
            html_file.write(html_code)
    
        # added try/except for the meantime to handle converting errors on some rows/html codes
        try:
            pdfkit.from_file(html_file_path, pdf_file_path, configuration = config, options = options)   # include configuration = config argument
                                                                                                  
        
            print(f'Converted {html_file_path} to {pdf_file_path}')  # to indicate if conversion is successful
        
        except:
            print(f'Converted {html_file_path} to {pdf_file_path} but with some error in wkhtmltopdf')  # to indicate if conversion is not successful
        

print('Conversion complete.')  # to indicate conversion completion
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
        exec(code, globals, locals)
    
      File c:\users\jdayao\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\untitled6.py:52
        html_file.write(html_code)
    
      File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py:19 in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u202f' in position 3929: character maps to <undefined>
```

Now having this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\jdayao\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\untitled11.py:64
    pdfkit.from_file(html_file_path, pdf_file_path, configuration = config, options = options)   # include configuration = config argument

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py:51 in from_file
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py:201 in to_pdf
    self.handle_error(exit_code, stderr)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py:155 in handle_error
    raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)

OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

Comment: Please put the whole traceback of the error inside of the question body.

Comment: ohh yeah, i included it now, thanks for checking!

Comment: Have you tried opening the output-file with the same encoding as the reading-file? `with open(html_file_path, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as html_file:`

Comment: woww nice it actually works! after adding the argument in output-file, thanks! but i have another error right now in another html code with below traceback error that matbe you can quickly suggest fix as well:

Comment: I've already edited my post to add my new error, and this will be my last error on my code since i've already fixed my other errors on other html codes embedded in csv file (200+ html codes)

Comment: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599970/how-to-solve-wkhtmltopdf-reported-an-error-exit-with-code-1-due-to-network-err) about the new error. Not sure if that solves your problem or not though. Also found [this comment](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2660#issuecomment-663063752) on an issue on the wkhtmltopdf repo about the same thing.